# Can an accented weak vowel in a diphthong ever not be emphasised?

Tags: acentuación, diptongos, sílabas

### English

If in a diphthong consisting of a weak (i, u) and a strong (a, e, o) vowel the emphasis lies on the weak vowel, an accent is put on it and the diphthong is pronounced in two syllables. For example, we write 'todavía' because it is pronounced as 'to-da-*vi*-a'. Are there any words with such a diphthong for which the weak vowel is accentuated and pronounced separately, but the emphasis lies on another syllable? In other words, if the weak vowel is accentuated in virtue of being pronounced separately, will it always be emphasized?

### Español

Si en un diptongo consistente en una vocal cerrada (i, u) y una abierta (a, e, o) el énfasis está en la vocal cerrada, se pone un acento en él y el diptongo se pronuncia en dos sílabas. Por ejemplo, se escribe 'todavía' porque se lo pronuncia como 'to-da-*vi*-a'. ¿Hay alguna palabra con así diptongo donde la vocal cerrada está acentuada y se pronuncia separadamente, pero el énfasis está en otra sílaba? En otras palabras, ¿si la vocal cerrada está acentuada para estar pronunciada separadamente, siempre se la enfatiza?

Comment: Strictly speaking, "todav**ía**" is not a _diphthong_ but a _hiatus_.

Comment: When you add an accent to a diphthong, it's no longer a diphthong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Qué es un diptongo? Es la pronunciación conjunta de dos vocales en una sola sílaba. En español se dan siempre que estén adyacentes una vocal fuerte (a, e, o) y una vocal débil (i, u) o dos vocales débiles.

¿Qué es un hiato? Es la pronunciación en sílabas separadas de dos vocales adyacentes.

- Siempre que hay un diptongo la vocal débil (o una de las dos) actúa como semiconsonante. Si este diptongo es la sílaba tónica, la vocal que se lleva el énfasis es la única que hace de vocal.

> agua | a-gua | [ˈa.ɣwa]

En este ejemplo vemos cómo la vocal débil no actúa como vocal sino como semiconsonante. También es un ejemplo en que el diptongo está en una sílaba átona.

> piano | pia-no

En este ejemplo la sílaba tónica es *pia-*, la *i* actúa como semiconsonante y el énfasis recae en la única vocal a efectos de pronunciación: la *a*.

- Siempre que se encuentren gráficamente una vocal débil y una fuerte (no importa el orden), o dos débiles, se pronunciará un diptongo (y por consiguiente la vocal débil será una semiconsonante). Sólo no pasará así si la vocal débil está enfatizada, es decir: 1) actúa como vocal, y 2) forma parte de la sílaba tónica de la palabra. En ese caso es imposible que la vocal adyacente forme parte de la misma sílaba.

> día | dí-a

Si no hubiera tilde sobre la *i* sería una palabra monosílaba, el énfasis recaería sobre la *a* y la *i* sólo sería una semiconsonante. Pero la partimos porque la *i* tiene «el peso», la sílaba tónica es *dí-*.

Comment: Una vocal abierta y cerrada, si no hay tilde en la cerrada, se consideran siempre como diptongo solo con el fin de tildar o acentuar gráficamente una palabra. Pero sobran ejemplos de palabras que forman hiato entre una vocal abierta y cerrada sin la presencia del tilde.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. But in most of those cases, the pronunciation may vary from person to person.

It's most evident with certain verbs that require accents in the present tense like:

- *enviar* — /en.**bi**'ar/ or /en'bjar/
- *continuar* — /kon.ti.**nu**'ar/ or /kon.ti'war/

and on words where the vowels are in different morphemes like:

- *estadounidense* — /es.ta.do.**u**.ni'den.se/

Comment: Gracias por esos ejemplos. He cambiado un poco mi pregunta: en particular soy interesado en el caso en que la vocal cerrada está acentuada.

Comment: @barto si lleva tilde, tendrá el acento obligatoriamente. El tilde marca la sílaba que lleva el acento, siempre. Que marca un hiato también es un efecto secundario.

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish every word has **only one** stressed vowel. Therefore, if the emphasis is on another vowel (away from diphthong) logically no vowel of the diphthong is accentuated.

Comment: A menos que sea adverbio. Los adverbios formados con *-mente* admiten una doble acentuación como en **rá**pida**me**nte

Comment: Toda la razón. Y por supuesto las palabras compuestas.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** La tilde sólo se usa para señalar la sílaba acentuada. En las otras sílabas los hiatos no se diferencian ortográficamente de los diptongos.

Ejemplo típico: cliente (*cli-en-te*) y diente (*dien-te*).