# Why does "reír" (to laugh) have an accent when the stress is already on the second syllable?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, acentuación

Since "reir" ends in a consonant, the stress falls on the second syllable. Therefore, why does "reír" have an accent on "i", which is part of the second syllable? **I've been taught that the infinitive forms of Spanish verbs always end in "ar", "er" or "ir"**. Is this considered normal?

Comment: I think this Q&A may help you here https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10577/can-an-accented-weak-vowel-in-a-diphthong-ever-not-be-emphasised?rq=1

Comment: Ending in ir does not mean it can't take an accent. Without one, it would be a dipthong.

Comment: The accent in "reír" serves the same function as in "maíz" and "tahúr". It separates two syllables that are meant to be pronounced apart, not as a diphtong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"i" is considered to be a weak vowel in Spanish, and "e" is considered a strong vowel. When a weak and a strong vowel in Spanish combines, **they form a diphthong**. As such, "ei" in "reir" would be treated as one sylable, and thus, "reir" **would be one syllable long** and the rule that *"word ends in consonant => stress on the last syllable"* does not apply. Therefore, in order to avoid confusion, one must have an accent on the last syllable to stress the last syllable.